# Why can't I shutdown tomcat 7 embedded from maven plugin?

Tags: windows, java-7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm using `tomcat7-maven-plugin` 2.2 to run a webapp from command line (I'm on Windows 8.1, Java 1.7.0_51 and Maven 3.2.1).

This is the configuration (pretty straightforward, I guess):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>

    <configuration>
        <address>localhost</address>
        <port>8080</port>
        <path>/</path>
        <uriEncoding>UTF-8</uriEncoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I run Maven with `mvn tomcat7:run` and it starts correctly, the server starts up, the webapp loads, and I can interact with it.
The command prompt in which I run Maven is busy showing Tomcat output (this looks fine to me):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <project-name-here> 0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ <project-name-here> >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ <project-name-here> ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 25 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ <project-name-here> ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ <project-name-here> <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ <project-name-here> ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at c:\workspace\<project-name-here>\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath:
apr 01, 2014 10:39:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
apr 01, 2014 10:39:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Informazioni: Starting service Tomcat
apr 01, 2014 10:39:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informazioni: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
apr 01, 2014 10:39:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
```

Then, I want to shutdown the server: I run `mvn tomcat7:shutdown` from a separate command prompt, but all I get is this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <project-name-here> 0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:shutdown (default-cli) @ <project-name-here> ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.083 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-01T10:39:59+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
"cmd" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
```

That last line reads:

> "cmd" is not a recognized internal or external command, an executable
>   or a batch file.

I can stop Tomcat from the first command prompt hitting `Ctrl+C`, but since I need to pass all this others, I'd like to offer them a script to start the webapp and a script to stop it.

What's wrong? Is it a plugin error? Is it a configuration error on my side?

---

**EDIT**

If I add `<fork>true</fork>` to the POM, the server crashes with this error:

```
[...]
Informazioni: Starting service Tomcat
apr 03, 2014 2:05:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informazioni: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
apr 03, 2014 2:05:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080"]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.711 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-03T14:05:31+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/368M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: IllegalAccessException for stop method in class org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.ExtendedTomcat
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.run.EmbeddedRegistry.shutdownAll(EmbeddedRegistry.java:110)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.run.EmbeddedRegistry$1.run(EmbeddedRegistry.java:69)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:351)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase$StopChild
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1173)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem but only when the integration tests are failing after a 'mvn verify' command. If they pass, I get a nice warning 'The executor associated with thread pool [http-bio-8087] has not fully shutdown. Some application threads may still be running.'.

Comment: Have you succeeded to solve this problem? I'm facing the same :( Restarting ecipse everytime I changes something, very annoying.

Comment: @Deckard Nope, and I moved away from that project a long time ago. But my question has nothing to do with Eclipse, this is when running Maven from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you need to use `Ctrl + c` after starting *Tomcat* server with `mvn tomcat7:run` to shut it down as it's attached to the current *Maven* run.

The **shutdown** goal is used to be called after e.g. performing some tests (integration tests) to finish all the job in a clean way.

Comment: I think also that the shutdown goal is not bound into any phase. Feel free to accept the answer and upvote it in case it helped figuring out the root matter :)

Comment: Of course ;-) I'll just wait if anybody can add up something more :-)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the fork option http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#fork

So with this option you are able to start embeded tomcat run some tests then shutdown.

HTH

Comment: Ugh, I forgot to add the error I get when using it, I edited the question now (the fork option makes Tomcat crash).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is if the Tomcat maven plugin had a way to enable the shutdown port (default 8005) then you can just send the default shutdown string (default "shutdown") to shut it down.

Using a JMX client, the shutdown port is set to -1 when I run the plugin run goal.