# How to stop, restart, republish automatically tomcat-plugin of maven on eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have used tomcat-plugin of maven to run my web application on eclipse IDE.
I used goal: *tomcat7:run*
I also known goal:  *tomcat7:shutdown* and executed it. But when i refresh my web page on browser then my application still run. Why?
So Can you help me how to stop or restart tomcat-plugin of maven. And how to configure tomcat-plugin to republish automatically.
Thanks so much!

Comment: hi, did you see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781039/why-cant-i-shutdown-tomcat-7-embedded-from-maven-plugin ?

Comment: but I run my app with maven on eclipse, not command line.

Comment: it makes no difference

Comment: Yeah. I see. so how to republish automatically ?

Comment: If you want to use it only in eclipse, then with the m2eclipse the redeploy works automatically. But you could watch this page : http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/. or configure the tomcat:redeploy phase, or use the cargo plugin https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2009/12/28/automated-deployment-cargo-and-maven-short-primer.
there's a lot of solution :)